# weed-fs in Linode running master

Tags: linode, weed-fs

I'm using weed-fs 0.7 beta.
I'm having an issue where the master server always does not have any free volume servers while i have 2 of them.
I have 2 servers in Linode, i used one of them to create a master, volume and filer server using this command.

```
./weed server -ip.bind="192.168.139.166" -master.port=9333 -volume.port=8080 -volume.max="7" -dir="./data" -master.dir="./master" -filer=true -filer.dir="./filer"
```

The 3 systems starts properly. But when i check the master server using this command:

```
curl "http://{IP-ADDRESS}:9333/dir/status?pretty=y"
```

This is the result:

```
{
  "Topology": {
    "DataCenters": null,
    "Free": 0,
    "Max": 0,
    "layouts": null
  },
  "Version": "0.70 beta"
}
```

I can add in file into the volume server directly using this:

```
curl -F file=help.txt http://{IP-ADDRESS}:8080/3,01637037d6
```

When i attempt to add the above file, this is the response on the console of the server:

```
I0512 08:30:06 20079 store.go:346] volume 3 size 20 will exceed limit 0
I0512 08:30:06 20079 store.go:348] error when reporting size: No master node available!
```

My best guess is that somehow the Master server does not seems to be able to detect the volume server, while both of them are on the same server.
I tried using my 2nd server to run volume server and point the master server's IP address using private IP, it does not work either.
But it seems like the volume servers are able to work without the master server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use -ip="192.168.139.166", instead of -ip.bind

Comment: if i replace it, it will crash after it finds the Master Server Leader.
But if i add that extra parameter, it is seen properly.
But some commands seems to still not working.

`curl "http://{IP-ADDRESS}.166:9333/cluster/status?pretty=y"`

`shows {
  "Peers": [
    "localhost:9333"
  ]`

While `curl "http://{IP-ADDRESS}:9333/dir/status?pretty=y"`
show nothing. Any idea